# Error at solving the ODE (SymPy) with one constant

Tags: python, sympy, ode, symbolic-math

I am trying to solve the following equation:

[image]

with this boundary condition: [image]

```
import sympy as sym

sym.init_printing()
t,m,k,g,v0,psi = sym.symbols("t,m,k,g,v_0,psi")

vz = sym.Function('v_z')(t)

a = vz.diff(t)

eqn = sym.Eq(-k*vz**2 - m*a - m*g,0)

sol = sym.simplify(sym.dsolve(eqn)).rhs

constant = sym.solve([sol.subs(t,0)-v0*sym.sin(psi)],dict=True)
```

However, the constant C1 is solved incorrectly:
[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You should tell `solve` which symbol you are trying to solve for. Also you can use the `ics` argument to `dsolve` to do this.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin Great, thank you very much for the hint with `ics`. It worked in this case. I had to change my code to:

`import sympy as sym
sym.init_printing()
t,m,k,g,v0,psi = sym.symbols("t,m,k,g,v_0,psi")

vz = sym.Function('v_z')

a = vz.diff(t)

eqn = sym.Eq(-k*vz(t)**2 - m*vz(t).diff(t) - m*g,0)

sol = sym.dsolve(eqn, ics = {vz(0): v0*sym.sin(psi)})`